# Tenforflow k-hot encodings?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I am continuing my learning of TensorFlow and I have achieved some success with making models. I'm getting deeper into the API and I am having some problems with terminology. I have a model of 273 features and 4 linearly independent (in the matrix sense) outputs (2^4=16 possible output vectors per input vector). In fact the first model was a simple matmul of sizes [1,273][273,4], which worked ok. To get to this step though, I had to perform a lot of manipulation. My python processing pipeline is described the steps below, so I'd like to know which tf functions I should be leveraging at each step?

1. Corpus is a csv with columns: y0,y1,y2,y3,sentence (You can skip this, CSV reading is well documented)
2. Scan corpus and extract the words used at least twice (to drop single misspellings) and convert to vectors.
3. Encode each sentence to it's vector representations. ([y0,y1,y2,y3],[x0,...,x273])

I did all the above in python manually, but I want to leverage as much of the TF API as possible. Unfortunately, it seems that 1-hot encoding gets a lot of support in the API and in order to use that I'd have to create and maintain 4 separate models. Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 linearly independent (in the matrix sense) outputs"? 4 possible value for your output (i.e. 4 output classes) or something else?

Comment: Linearly independent means that they don't affect each other, that is to say, a set of 4 dimensional vectors: [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0] , [0,0,1,0] , [0,0,0,1], They are not mutually exclusive, they are less than that, they are not linearly dependent. It's like 4 wall switches, each of which flip 4 separate lights. S.A.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence.

Comment: Imagine dimensions as size (1=big, 0=small), dB (1=loud,0=quiet), rotation (1=spinning, 0=not spinning) and  temperature (1=hot, 0=cold). The status of size does not in any way determine temperature, etc.

Comment: I was not asking for what is "linearly independent" in general but rather what do you mean by that. So, you have 4 binary linearly independent outputs? Because the 1st model you mentioned "a simple matmul of sizes [1,273][273,4]" is not exactly that.

Comment: That may be a good point. I had thought like in linear algebra, that since the dimensions were linearly independent, that it could do all 4 at once.  So instead of [1,273]*[273,1] = [1,1] I could get [1,273]*[273,4] = [1,4] out of it. The weights for each dimension are there, so I thought that gradient descent would be able to find appropriate weights, most likely eliminating any non-trivial weighting between dimensions (unless it was relevant)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a k_hot function in tf either. It is a good idea to do multi label rather than having several models if features can be shared !

So here is a function doing it. It is basically summing several one_hot encodings of your vector.

```
def k_hot(vector, num_classes):
  one_hot_in_lines = tf.one_hot(vector, num_classes)
  return tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_in_lines, axis=0)
```

Let's see how it works :

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
vector = [0, 2]
num_classes = 3
one_hot_in_lines = tf.one_hot(vector, num_classes) 
>> [[1., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]
k_hot_encoding = tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_in_lines, axis=0) 
>> [1., 0., 1.]

# with the function:
k_hot(vector) 
>> [1., 0., 1.]
```